# MySQL Partition date range index behavior

Tags: mysql, indexing, partition

I have a table where I partitioned on a DATE column by month. I also added an index on this same column:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_aggregate` (
    `bus_date` date NOT NULL,
    `col01` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `col02` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(bus_date) ) (
    PARTITION lt201001 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2010-01-01 00:00:00') ), 
    PARTITION lt201201 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-01-01 00:00:00') ), 
    ...
    PARTITION lt201501 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2015-01-01 00:00:00') ), 
    PARTITION ltMAX VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);

ALTER TABLE report_aggregate ADD INDEX('bus_date');
```

Now when I do a query with a single date specified, it uses the index:
SELECT * FROM report_aggregate WHERE bus_date = '2014-09-01';

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | report_aggregate   | lt201410   | ref  | bus_date      | bus_date | 3       | const | 59728 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

If I do a query with two days, it also uses the index:
SELECT * FROM report_aggregate WHERE bus_date >= '2014-09-01' AND bus_date <= '2014-09-02';

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | report_aggregate   | lt201410   | range | bus_date      | bus_date | 3       | NULL | 123232 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

SELECT * FROM `report_aggregate` WHERE bus_date IN('2014-09-01', '2014-09-10');

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | report_aggregate   | lt201410   | range | bus_date      | bus_date | 3       | NULL | 120302 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

If I do a query with 3 or more days, it does not use the index:
SELECT * FROM report_aggregate WHERE bus_date >= '2014-09-01' AND bus_date <= '2014-09-03';

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | report_aggregate   | lt201410   | ALL  | bus_date      | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 751901 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

And it does not matter if the date range is contiguous or not, you can use >= with <=, an IN(), or a BETWEEN... whenever a query filters on 3 or more unique dates, it no longer uses the index.
Ex. SELECT * FROM report_aggregate WHERE bus_date IN('2014-09-01','2014-09-10','2014-09-15');

```
  +----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | report_aggregate   | lt201410   | ALL  | bus_date      | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 751901 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Also notice it's not spanning across multiple partitions, and EXPLAIN PARTITIONS always reports that one partition is being used (lt201410). I mention this because I had thought that perhaps it could not use an index across partitions, but since it's only using one partition, this has been ruled out.

Any idea why it does not use the index with more than 2 dates included in the filter?

Comment: How much rows are in those tables? You better post the result of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) <your query> too.

Comment: added EXPLAIN PARTITIONS results to each example query